# How to cross product list of lists in python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

If I have list of lists

```
A = [a, b, ..., d]
```

in Python, then how can I apply [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to it?

I know that I can crossproduct over explicit lists

```
import itertools
for combination in itertools.product(a, b, ..., d):
   ...
```

but how to deal with dynamic list of lists like `A`?

Comment: Unpack `A`: `for combination in itertools.product(*A)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#calls) the function arguments from the list:

```
A = [a, b, ..., d] 

for combination in itertools.product(*A):
    ...
```

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: I down-voted this answer because this question is a common duplicate, and I'm afraid this answer really doesn't add any substantially information over the other answers.